# MongoDB monk collection name: UserX + UserY

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, chat

Using front end Vue.js we (users) try to join a private chat.
Using MongoDB to store messages in the collection "XY",
where:

- X - UserX._id (req.user._id)
- Y - UserY._id (toUser._id - selected    user from user list)

=> collection name "UserX+UserY", something like *5ef630dfbe431b28e0d97823* + *5ef4fa80c3a5071e2055b507* = 5ef630dfbe431b28e0d978235ef4fa80c3a5071e2055b507.

-A user list is shown in front end (by reading the username accounts from database)

**The problem:**

1. UserX starts a chat by selecting (with a click) an UserY - MongoDB collection **"UserX+UserY"** is created.
2. UserY clicks UserX -  MongoDB collection **"UserY+UserX"**

When UserY tries to join the chat, I need to get first the already existing room, to make UserY join it, not creating another chat.

Reversing the userIDs from roomName(collection) it's the problem.

**I tried to solve by lexicographically comparing the substrings from the collection name.**
If a collection containing **BOTH** substrings (user IDs) I need to make users join that room.The substring order is not important.

- I'll use web sockets to let users read the messages in real-time. Post requests are made just with the regular HTTP request.

  ```
      if(toUserId !== myUserId) {
    // room id must have BOTH user 1 & user 2
    var rooms = db_room.find({ /* all */});
    var index = db_room.get({ $indexOfArray: [ myUserId + toUserId ] });

    var existingRoom1 = myUserId > toUserId // this lexicographically compares two strings
      ? myUserId + toUserId
      : toUserId + myUserId;
     var existingRoom2 = myUserId < toUserId
      ? myUserId + toUserId
      : toUserId + myUserId;

  // indexOf - search position by string === string
  // .includes - on letters, can be use x && y, substring of string => result boolean

   // if(rooms.includes(existingRoom1) + rooms.includes(existingRoom2))
   if(db_room.get( {$in: existingRoom1()} ) + db_room.get( {$in: existingRoom2} ))
      { // exists or not, true or false

        // find name of the room containing myUserId && toUserId
        // emit join in this.room (join with indexNr)
        if( index == -1 ) {
          index = rooms.indexOf(toUserId + myUserId);
        }// if not found

        console.log(`room ${room} exists: \n`);
        console.log(index);

        var roomXY = rooms[index];
        // true, emit Join event to clients.
        // MongoDB.getCollection(this.collection).insert({ UserX + UserY })
        //socket.join(roomXY, myUserId, toUserId);
        //var i = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.sids).indexOf(toUserId);
        console.log(`${toUserId} e nr ${i}`);
    } else {
     // create the room firsty, after join.
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend simplifying your room naming code. You can have both users choose the same room name without checking the DB. So, working from the top,  your code could be:

```
if(toUserId !== myUserId) {
  let roomName = toUserID < myUserId ? toUserId+myUserId : myUserId+toUserId;
```

Now, both users can check the DB to see if that room name has to be created or already exists, emit the "join" event referenced in your code, and post messages.